# Java memory optimized [Key:Long, Value:Long] store of very large size (500M) for concurrent read-access

Tags: java, collections, guava, apache-commons

I have a use-case where I need to store Key - Value pairs of size approx. 500 Million entries in sinle VM of size 8 GB. Key and Value are of type Long. Key is auto incremented starting from 1, 2 ,3, so on..

Only once I build this Map[K-V] structure at the start of program as a exclusive operation, Once this is build, used only for lookup, No update or delete is performed in this structure.

I have tried this with java.util.hashMap but as expected it consumes a lot of memory and program give OOM : Heap usage exceeds Error.

I need some guidance on following which helps in reducing the memory footprint, I am Ok with some degradation in access performance.

1. What are the other alternative (from java collection or other libraries)
   that can be tried here.
2. What is a recommended way to get the memory footprint by this Map, for
   comparison purpose.

Comment: Just use a `long[]`.  500 million ascending keys is less than 2^31.  And if you go over 2^31, use a `long[][]` where the first dimension is small and the second one is large.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a `long[]` or `long[][]`.

500 million ascending keys is less than 2^31.  And if you go over 2^31, use a `long[][]` where the first dimension is small and the second one is large.

(When the key type is an integer, you only need a complicated "map" data structure if the key space is sparse.)

The space wastage in a 1D array is insignificant.  Every Java array node has 12 byte header, and the node size is rounded up to a multiple of 8 bytes.  So a 500 million entry `long[]` will take so close to 500 million x 8 bytes == 4 billion bytes that it doesn't matter.

However, a JVM typically cannot allocate a single object that takes up the entire available heap space.  If virtual address space is at a premium, it would be advisable to use a 2-D array; e.g. `new long[4][125_000_000]`.  This makes the lookups slightly more complicated, but you will most likely *reduce* the memory footprint by doing this.

---

If you don't know beforehand the number of keys to expect, you could do the same thing with a combination of arrays and `ArrayList` objects.  But an `ArrayList` has the problem that if you don't set an (accurate) capacity, the memory utilization is liable to be suboptimal.  And if you populate an `ArrayList` by appending to it, the instantaneous memory demand for the `append` can be as much as 3 times the list's current space usage.

Comment: stephen, what if we do not know the array-length prior...?

Comment: Well you should be able to use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: You can also go for more than two dimensions. Mind that in Java multi-dimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays and array references can be `null`. It’s possible to support the entire `long` range with a sparse array that way.

Comment: Hmmm  ... yes ... but it is more complicated complicated to build.  And while you don't need to populate the entire "tree" of arrays, you still end up consuming more memory because the individual array objects have a higher header to size ratio ... and because you still need to store the nulls that you refer to.  Besides, "key is auto incremented" implies that the key space is not sparse.

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked that “Key is auto incremented starting from 1, 2 ,3, …”. Then, there is no need for a long key at all and a plain array will do.

Comment: Basically yes.  Though if you are memory constrained it might pay to avoid allocating a single huge array object.

Comment: Stephen, bit confused, in a scenario where total values being stored are not known ( fixed) prior  and memory optimisation is primarily aspect, what is a best fit? Both array and Arraylist has its own issue?

Comment: The best option in terms memory optimization will be for >you< to thoroughly research the various options, implement them, benchmark them, profile them, optimize them, and finally make a decision based on the performance of the (different) optimized solutions.  Sorry, but you are asking us to make a prediction based on insufficient information about a very specific use-case that I / we don't have direct experience with.

Comment: Standard advice on something like this is to avoid "premature optimization".  Implement the simple version, get it working, then worry about performance later when you have more information.  In this case, that means the flat array: `long[]`.  Allocate it to be bigger than you expect it to need to be, and if it is too small, crash and restart with a larger number.  That's the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for using a `Map` in your case.

If you just have a start index and further indizes are just constant increments, just use a `List`:

```java
List<Long> data=new ArrayList<>(510_000_000);//capacity should ideally not be reached, if it is reached, the array behind the ArrayList needs to be reallocated, the allocated memory would be doubled by that

data.add(1337L);//inserting, how often you want

long value=data.get(1-1);//1...your index that starts with 1, -1...because your index starts with 1, you should subtract one from the index.
```

If you don't even add more elements and know the size from the start, an array will be even better:

```java
long[] data=long[510_000_000];//capacity should surely not be reached, you will need to create a new array and copy all data if it is higher
int currentIndex=0;

data[currentIndex++]=1337L//inserting, as often as it is smaller than the size

long value=data[1-1];//1...your index that starts with 1, -1...because your index starts with 1, you should subtract one from the index.
```

Note that you should check the index (`currentIndex`) before inserting so that it is smaller than the array length.

When iterating, use `currentIndex+1` as length instead of `.length`.

Create an array with the size you need and whenever you need to access it, use `arr[i-1]` (`-1` because your indizes start with `1` instead of zero).

If you "just" have 500 million entries, you will not reach the integer limit and a simple array will be fine.

If you need more entries and you have sufficient memories, use an array of arrays.

The memory footprint of using an array this big is the memory footprint of the data and a bit more.

However, if you don't know the size, you should use a higher length/capacity then you may need. If you use an `ArrayList`, the memory footprint will be doubled (temporarily tripled) whenever the capacity is reached because it needs to allocate a bigger array.

A `Map` would need an object for each entry and an array of lists for all those object that would highly increase the memory footprint. The increasing of the memory footprint (using `HashMap`) is even worse than with `ÀrrayList`s as the underlaying array is reallocated even if the `Map` is not completely filled up.

But consider saving it to the HDD/SSD if you need to store that much data. In most cases, this works much better. You can use `RandomAccessFile` in order to access the data on the HDD/SSD on any point.

Comment: dan1st, Thanks for your reply...Will give a try to this. Want to understand this better "The memory footprint of using an array this big is the memory footprint of the data and a bit more." - For example if one has a `long[] longArray = new long[10];`; memory footprint after storing the data will be 10 * 8 + 1 = 81 bytes.. Is this correct...? Additional byte is for storing array start offset?

Comment: Actually, the overhead is more than one byte as the JVM needs to store the length of the array and arrays are also objects what increases the overhead a bit but that overhead is disappearing with large arrays. The offset of one byte does not need to be stored in the array, however.